# Finding the direction with GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

Please consider this scenario:

An app knows which of a few routes the phone is on, thanks to GPS. That means it knows the only two directions that the device will be traveling in.

Am I right in thinking that the best way to determine which direction the phone is moving (it will almost certainly not be pointing the right way, so compass is not an option) is to poll the GPS until it starts moving, and find the direction the Co-Ords are moving in?

How regularly, and for how long, do you suggest the polling polls/lasts for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds about right. You might get some useful data from the inbuilt accelerometer, too. It's not so useful if someone has it in their pocket whilst walking (the rocking motion makes things awkward), but it's very useful when the phone is relatively stationary within a moving vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a science in itself, read up on kalman filtering. Basically, the difference between the last two points given by the GPS is the direction you are moving. Then errors come into the equation and you need to start learning about good ways to filter the data and get better results.

Attempt at explaining kalman filtering:

A kalman filter uses a Model to predict new values for the predicted thing. It makes an assumption like "stuff usually moves in the direction of their speed. so if it was here a second ago, it will be there now". It will then use this model to predict the next point and when it actually can measure the next point, it will use that data to update the model and assess the accuracy of the prediction. Then it will start giving you predictions based on a combination of real data and predictions which are weighted according to it's measurements of the prediction accuracy. So if the model is normally very accurate but there is suddenly a jump in the data, it will assume that it is a fluke and it will not let it affect the value too much. If the data is very jumpy, it will trust the data more and the model less.

Comment: You may want to add some information as to how OP might go about using Kalman filtering, and some background on how it works. Even a link to Wikipedia would be useful! :)

Comment: I assumed he can google and if you put kalman filtering into google it will pop up the wikipedia article on it. And explaining it here is a futile task.